# IE11 Internet Options in Interactive Services Detection Window

Tags: java, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, testng, internet-explorer-11

I'm running tests in Win10 with Jenkins, Selenium InternetExplorerDriver and TestNG and the tests should run in Interactive Services Detection window with IE11. I have set up all the things, but the problem is that I'm stuck with the tests because I'm not able to change internet options fast enough before the test crashes. 
First of all the Win10 doesn't let me use mouse or keyboard in Interactive Services Detection window so I need to take VNC connection with UltraVNC to make those work. 
Secondly the VNC connection is too slow so the test has already crashed before I'm able to change the internet options.
Thirdly, changing the protected mode settings to the IE on my desktop doesn't change the settings to the IE running on Interactive Services Detection window.

This is the  error I get to Jenkins console when running test:

> [testng] FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeSuite startSelenium    [testng]
>   org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unexpected error
>   launching Internet Explorer. Protected Mode settings are not the same
>   for all zones. Enable Protected Mode must be set to the same value
>   (enabled or disabled) for all zones.

I asked earlier in this that is there any global settings for IE11 that could affect also the IE in Interactive Services Detection window, but I tried to change the protected mode settings globally by editing settings with Local group policy editor, but that didn't affect to IE in Interactive Services Detection window. 
I'm really out of ideas at the moment so I hope someone could guide me to right direction.

Answer (score 0):

After days and hours of searching the right solution for my problem the answer was finally quite simple. I added introduceFlakinessByIgnoringSecurityDomains() capability and put thread to sleep for 50 seconds to give me time to make all the changes to Internet Options. Here is my code that solved the problem:

```
InternetExplorerOptions capability = new InternetExplorerOptions();
capability.introduceFlakinessByIgnoringSecurityDomains();
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capability);
try {
    Thread.sleep(50000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

After changing the security options I commented capability and thread.sleep lines away so those wont disturb running the test cases.